# General form of a matrix $M$ commutes with the unitary representation $U^{\otimes m},~ \forall U\in U(n)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, linear-algebra

My question is about the general form of a $n^m\times n^m$ positive definite matrix $M$ where 
$$[M,U^{\otimes m}]=0,~ \forall U\in U(n)$$
or in other words, M commutes with all members of the the unitary representation $U \mapsto U^{\otimes m}$. This representation is reducible, so let $\pi_i$'s be projectors onto invariant subspaces. Since $[\pi_i,U^{\otimes m}]=0$, one form of $M$ could be a linear combination of $\pi_i$'s, i.e. $$M=\sum_i t_i ~\pi_i,~ t_i\geq 0$$
Is this the most general form of $M$ and if not, what is that?

Comment: No. This would be true if and only if each irreducible subrepresentation of $V^{\otimes m}$ (with $V=\mathbb{C}^n$  the standard representation) occurred with multiplicity 1; 
but this is already false for $n=2$, $m=3$: $V^{\otimes 3}\cong \mathrm{Sym}^3V\oplus V\oplus V$. 
This means that you have to add the intertwining operators.

Answer (score 2):

If you were asking about matrices which commute with the action of $GL_n$ instead of $U(n)$, the answer would be Schur-Weyl Duality: the space of intertwiners is spanned by the matrices which permute the different tensor factors of $\mathbb{C}^n$.
I believe that the answer should be the same also if you consider just the unitary matrices.

Comment: Yes, this is true. A sketch is that the space of intertwiners for $GL_n$ is the same as the space of intertwiners for $\mathfrak{gl}_n$, and since $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ is the complexification of $\mathfrak{u}(n)$ it's also the same as the space of intertwiners for $\mathfrak{u}(n)$, and hence for $U(n)$. For more details see: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/four-flavors-of-schur-weyl-duality/